# Terminal commands implemented as C++20 coroutines

Tags: c++, coroutine

I'm programming my project in modern **C++20**. This app is like a *terminal/console* in graphics mode, where you can type commands with their respective parameters, the terminal will recognize the first word, and it if founds it within it's internal map, it calls the mapped function (the command itself). This works great. But now, I realized that some commands will require user interaction. For example, if I want to recreate the **del** command from **MS-DOS**, and the user types `del *.bak /p`, the command will need to get a character from the keyboard (`y` for yes, `n` for no). Some other commands will require an entire string to be typed by the user. How can I do this? I was thinking to implement my commands as **coroutines**, so I can suspend execution letting the terminal know I want a single character or a full string, then resume. But I find coroutines to be somewhat complicated. So far, I have this code

```
enum class e_command_input { SINGLE_CHAR, STRING };

class OS_Command
{
    public:

        // Forward declaration
        struct promise_type;

        using t_handle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

        struct promise_type
        {
            // Creates the command
            auto get_return_object() -> OS_Command
            {
                return OS_Command{ t_handle::from_promise(*this) };
            }

            auto initial_suspend() -> std::suspend_always
            {
                cout << "    Command starts running" << endl;
                return {};
            }

            auto final_suspend() noexcept -> std::suspend_always
            {
                cout << "    Command finishes running" << endl;
                return {};
            }

            void return_void()
            {
            }

            void unhandled_exception()
            {
                m_except = std::current_exception();
            }


            // data
            std::exception_ptr m_except{};
        };


    public:

        // ctor
        OS_Command(t_handle handle)
            : m_handle(handle)
        {
        }

        // Cannot be copyed
        OS_Command(OS_Command&) = delete;

        // dtor
        ~OS_Command()
        {
            if (m_handle)
                m_handle.destroy();
        }


        // Manually start
        void start()
        {
            cout << "Coro start() called" << endl;
            m_handle.resume();
        }

    private:

        // Access to the state of the coroutine
        t_handle m_handle;

};


// Coroutine "factory"? that returns a coroutine object
auto make_command() -> OS_Command
{
    // Is THIS the real coroutine???
    co_await std::suspend_never{};
}


//
int main()
{
    cout << "main: Before command" << endl;

    auto cmd1 = make_command();
    cmd1.start();

    cout << "main: After command" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and works, but I don't understand:

- Where should I implement the code for the command? Where to write the co_yield and co_return statements?
- How can I pass the enum to my Terminal class (the caller), and how to get back the user typed std::string or character from the terminal?
- Is *make_command()* the real coroutine here? is it a factory?

Comment: Coroutines are complicated, yes. Perhaps consider using a ready-made coroutines library like cppcoro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So C++ language level coroutines are building blocks that let you build async libraries other languages provide directly.

This in theory lets you extend your async idioms with new ones, and not just use the pre-defined ones provided by the language.

Imagine, if you would, that if instead of providing inheritance and virtual functions and the like, C++ instead provided a language where you can define your own model of inheritance and message passing.  This would be more powerful, but really annoying when all you wanted to do was have an interface with a method that you could inherit from and implement.

In this case, C++ is providing hooks for you to define what co_yield, co_await and similar *mean*.  You could use the C++ coroutine system to invent async optionals with an exception like side channel and each co_await bypasses the expression to early exit with a nullopt, so `{ return co_await a + co_await b; }` is rewritten to be `{if(!a) return nullopt; if(!b) return nullopt; return *a+*b; }`

That level of flexibility means that you have a lot of framework work to do if you want to write your own coroutine type.

But all is not lost.

You can try to find an already written coroutine that does what you want.

But if you want to write one yourself, you should first step back and think about functions.

A function is a thingy.  You can do things to a function both within the function, and outside the function.

From outside the function you can pass it arguments, pass it a spot to out a return value, and execute it.  From inside the function you can get at the passed arguments, and you can set a return value, and you can exit the function.

Now we bundle these operations up in C++ - `R x = foo(a,b,c);` passes arguments, passes a return value, and starts execution all in one statement.  However, you could easily imagine doing this in multiple steps.

Inside the function similarly we require it to get the arguments first, and set the return value immediately before exiting.

C++ stoees the arguments and return value of a function on a thread local stack.  But in a language that separated those operations storing the arguments and return data on the heap or in a datastructure would be reasonable.

You can sort of do this with std async with launch policy deferred - the arguments are stored not in the thread local stack, but bubdled up and waiting for their use.  Even the return value is not stored on the stack until you choose to run the function.

Coroutines are functions with a bunch more operations on them.

When yiu first call a coroutine, it is likely to act a bit like a factory.  It doesn't have to!  But if you intend to interaft with it it probably will.

So consider the initial function call of most coroutines a bit like calling `sts::async(std::launch_policy::dederred,`  - you are setting up the work, not doing it yet.

Once you have set up the work, you kick it off.  This could consist of doing a co_await from another coroutine, or doing a `handle.resume()`.  The cresume is going to be called from a public method of the coroutine object you returned when you first invoked the coroutine.

To permit co_await you have to be awaitable - there is an entire cobtract for that.

Wimhen you first invoke the coroutine, a bunch of automatic steps inreacting with the provided classes occur.  A coroutine handle is created and passed to your provided class, and stuff is set up.  Eventually initial suspend is run - here, you are asked if you want to return immediately to the caller, or if you want to run cose in the body of your coroutine.

I'd advise initial suspending for your problem.  Then your coroutine is going to act like a factory like you said.

The caller has now created your "process" object.  It shoudl now resume it and see what comes out of it.  It could be a request for input, ir maybe a process termination.

Inside the coroutine body, you'll use co_return for process completion, and co_yield for requesting some service from the shell.  Alternatively, the shell could pass in an awaitable service object, and the process coroutine could co_await on input from it; this in turn would yield back to the shell.

The code that calls resume on the handle is responsible for ferrying any information back to the caller.  When the coroutine co_yields or co_awaits it interacts with your coroutine object in specific ways, giving you a chance to copy return values or whatever.  Then in the code after the resume you can figure out what data you stashed away, and if it was a return or a yield, abd communicate it back to the called.

```
Process p = CreateProc("command");
if(p.syntaxError()) {
  // blah
  return;
}
while (auto x = p.step()){
  query_user(x);
}
print(p.errcode());
```

and within the coroutine:

```
Process CreateProc(string s){
  auto parsed = parse_cmd(s);
  co_yield parse.success();
  // do stuff
  co_yield io_request;
  // do stuff
  co_yield io_request;
}
```

but doing this with a co_await is more fun:

```
Process CreateProc(string s, Io io){
  // ...
  x = co_await io.get("%d");
}
```

because co_await can suspend the coroutine and return a value in the body of the coroutine, which is closer to what you want.

Now, a provlem you'll have is that functions called from coroutines cannot suspend their calling coroutine.  Which means your suspendable work within a coroutine has to in turn be a coroutine.

C++ coroutines are stackless.

Your couroutine can await other coroutines and eventually reach one that awaits io, which suspends everything back to the original process being created in order to do the io work, which then resumes the entire chain to deliver the user input.

But at some point you have to ask why.  Why not just process the io deep in the call stack?

Comment: Let me see if I get it. The **CreateProc** function in your example is the real coroutine, because that is what uses `co_yield / co_await`. Right? So each command should be implemented like that?

Comment: @darknight in C++ the coroutine is the function that has co_await/co_yield/co_return in it.  Not an object, nor an instance, but the code itself.  It gets transformed in specified ways.  How you use that transformation is up to you: I described common patterns.  A lazy way is to use a std generator based coroutime.  I am uncertain if your use case matches C++ coroutines.